# Finding CPU spikes culprit

Tags: php, wordpress, performance, cpu

I'm running a **Wordpress blog** on **shared hosting**.
I don't have that much traffic (max. **4000 views per day** / 20 visitors at the same time).

I have checked everything I could on the Wordpress site e.g.:

- tried a standard theme (Twenty Twelve)
- deactivated all plugins
- disabled Cron jobs
- sped up website with common tips given by GMetrix etc.

My website [normally loads](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/zoomingjapan.com/8Hz1FTN7) in 4-6s, but sometimes due to the slow server response it's over 20s. This is caused by a spike in CPU usage according to my hosting provider (HawkHost).

I've been in contact with my hosting provider, but they couldn't solve the issue. I need to find the culprit.
I'm using Putty, but that doesn't really help.

I'm on shared hosting with 1 CPU core, which should be enough given my low stats.

Something is causing the CPU spikes. They don't happen 24/7, but several times a day.

My hosting service said I either should hire a developer to check my Wordpress installation or upgrade to dedicated hosting. Both will cost a lot of money and none might help in the end.

Does anyone here have experience with this and could help me figure out what I can do now?

For reference, here's a screenshot of my Putty log:

[image]
[image]

My cpanel CSU usage snapshot:
http://i64.tinypic.com/158321j.jpg

I'd be very grateful if anybody could help.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Because you're on shared hosting, other websites could spike up causing your website to slow down...

Comment: Ok, but that's not was my shared webhosting service is telling me. They tell me something is wrong with my WP installation or the code and that I should hire a developer to fix it. :(